# Query de consulta ignorando meses sem valor

Tags: mysql, sql-select

estou com uma dificuldade de gerar uma query, que conte a quantidade de registros que um operador efetuou nos últimos 3 meses, e me de a média apenas referente aos meses que tiveram resultados.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), MONTH(dataRegistro) AS mes FROM tb_agendamentos WHERE usuario = '8200' AND month(dataRegistro) BETWEEN '7' AND '9'
GROUP BY mes
```

com a query a cima, consigo até a quantidade de registros dos últimos 3 meses, mas preferia não ter que tratar o resultado via programação.

as variáveis relacionadas ao período de consulta, serão enviadas via programação, pois o período não será estática.
o problema seria pegar a média de acordo com os meses no qual tem resultado.

Comment: `BETWEEN MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) - 2 AND MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())` não resolveria? Ou, se não existir a possibilidade de ter registros em datas futuras, poderia fazer apenas `>= MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) - 2` - tratar o caso especial de Janeiro, onde o -2 não funcionaria como seria esperado.

Comment: as variáveis relacionadas ao período de consulta, serão enviadas via programação, pois o período não será estática. o problema seria pegar a média de acordo com os meses no qual tem resultado.

Comment: *"me de a média apenas referente aos meses que tiveram resultados."* isso parece meio obvio certo? não se pode retornar dados se não tiver registros :) pelo que entendi quer que retorno o mês mesmo que não tenha registros com o valor zero é isso?

Comment: na verdade, quero que a média seja apenas dos meses que tiveram registros, por exemplo, se o usuário é novo talvez tenha registros apenas em dois meses, então a média deveria ser apenas desses dois meses.
não estou conseguindo aplicar essa média com o count, no caso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui obter a média realizando o select dentro de um select.

```
SELECT nome, AVG(qtd) FROM (
    SELECT nome, COUNT(*) AS qtd, dataRegistro FROM tb_agendamentos
    WHERE month(dataRegistro) BETWEEN '7' AND '9' AND usuario = '8200'
    GROUP BY dataRegistro
)tu
```

Answer (score 0):

Para casos assim utilize o HAVING.

```
SELECT AVG(qtd), 
MONTH(dataRegistro) AS mes 
FROM tb_agendamentos 
WHERE 
    usuario = '8200' 
AND month(dataRegistro) BETWEEN '7' AND '9'
GROUP BY mes

HAVING AVG(qtd)>0
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).